# Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 2, column 1 (byte 2): Logstash

Tags: logging, logstash

I've been getting this weird error for some time now:

> Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 2, column 1 (byte 2) after

### Configuration:

```
input {
    stdin {}
    udp {
        type => "udp"
        port => "5959"
    }
    file {
        type => "syslog"
        path => "/var/log/messages"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => localhost
    }
}
```

### Command:

```
bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have some unsupported non-printed character in the original file. Incorrect EOL or whatever.

This example works fine with my logstash.
Try to copy and paste this config (from your post) to a new file and try it again.

Good luck.

Comment: My files was UTF8 with BOM, which appears to not be valid. Changed it to ASCII and it worked great. Thanks.